# How can I optimize my query using 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello everybody I have a long query and I'm trying to reduce it with less words and try to optimize it.

Here is my query:

```
SET @year := 2013;
SET @euro := 3.14;

SELECT
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-01') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Jan,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-02') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Feb,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-03') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Mar,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-04') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Apr,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-05') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) May,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-06') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Jun,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-07') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Jul,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-08') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Aug,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-09') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Sep,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-10') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Oct,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-11') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) Nov,
SUM(IF (CONCAT(@year, '-12') BETWEEN date_format(date_ini, '%Y-%m') AND date_format(date_expired, '%Y-%m'),i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1), 0)) `Dec`

FROM insurances  i
INNER JOIN policies p ON p.id = i.policy_id
WHERE (i.initial_date >= p.date_ini
AND i.final_date   <= p.date_expired)
```

Here is my result:

```
JAN      FEB    MAR      APR    MAY      JUN    JUL      AUG    SEP      OCT    NOV     DEC
20286   20286   26496   26496   26496   26496   26496   26496   9936    9936    9936    9936
```

Here is my demo:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/074ff/1

Please somebody can help me?

I will really appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative for you.

This may be a little longer due to the creation of the @sqlvars, but it should help in a couple ways.

The first FROM  (subselect that creates the sqlvars) is doing nothing except creating 12 simple variables representing the "dt" date of each month Jan-Dec as a date format and we get rid of all the character string concatenation done on every record for the date and the corresponding  from/to dates.

The second FROM (subselect is querying only those qualified records for the date range in question, yet while it's there, it computes the @euro factor there into a final column name "InsAmount".

Finally, those merged together simplifies the SUM() aggregate readability factor.

```
SET @euro := 3.14;

SELECT
      SUM( IF ( @dtJan BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Jan,
      SUM( IF ( @dtFeb BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Feb,
      SUM( IF ( @dtMar BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Mar,
      SUM( IF ( @dtApr BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Apr,
      SUM( IF ( @dtMay BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) May,
      SUM( IF ( @dtJun BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Jun,
      SUM( IF ( @dtJul BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Jul,
      SUM( IF ( @dtAug BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Aug,
      SUM( IF ( @dtSep BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Sep,
      SUM( IF ( @dtOct BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Oct,
      SUM( IF ( @dtNov BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) Nov,
      SUM( IF ( @dtDec BETWEEN date_ini AND date_expired, InsAmount, 0)) `Dec`
   from 
      ( select 
              @dtJan := '2013-01-01',
              @dtFeb := DATE_ADD( @dtJan, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtMar := DATE_ADD( @dtFeb, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtApr := DATE_ADD( @dtMar, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtMay := DATE_ADD( @dtApr, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtJun := DATE_ADD( @dtMay, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtJul := DATE_ADD( @dtJun, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtAug := DATE_ADD( @dtJul, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtSep := DATE_ADD( @dtAug, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtOct := DATE_ADD( @dtSep, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtNov := DATE_ADD( @dtOct, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ),
              @dtDec := DATE_ADD( @dtNov, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) ) sqlvars,
      ( select
              date_ini,
              date_expired,
              i.net_insurance * IF (type_money = 2, @euro, 1) as InsAmount
           from
              insurances  i
                 INNER JOIN policies p ON i.policy_id = p.id
           WHERE 
                  i.initial_date >= p.date_ini
              AND i.final_date   <= p.date_expired ) as QryRecs
```

Comment: thanks @DRapp but is it an optimization? because i wanted less code =)

Comment: @CarlitosMorales, less code? not necessarily, but I would consider running some timed tests on it vs yours and see the difference.  SOMETIMES, a little extra (such as the preparing of the 12 variables per month) and pre-gathering your qualified records times Euro or not rate can significantly clear up readability of code... which in-turn, can result in easier maintainability too.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to do a pivot query, which MySQL doesn't support. As you can see, the workaround gets VERY ugly, VERY fast.

Your ONLY alternatives are to switch to a DBMS that does support `PIVOT` queries, or revert to a conventional `SELECT ... FROM ...` query WITHOUT all of the conditional column logic, and do the rows->columns transformation in your client-side code.

Comment: How should be the query with less words?

Comment: ditch ALL of those `SUM(IF(` bits, and have a simple `select field_you_want FROM table`. Then use your client-side code to convert the individual row values into your multi-column data set. In other words, un-pivot your query